# Is MariaDB really caching or reusing “WITH” intermediary results?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, subquery

I have a MariaDB SQL query (actually very big) using chaining WITH statements like this :

```
WITH tbl_base AS (

    -- Base level sub-query on a table containing about 22000 rows, using LEFT JOIN on 5 other tables, details not relevant here
    SELECT ……… FROM <many things>

), tbl_middle AS (

    -- Intermediate level sub-query #1 for intermediate computing, details not relevant here
    SELECT ……… FROM tbl_middle …

), tbl_states AS (

    -- Intermediate level sub-query #2 for intermediate computing, details not relevant here
    SELECT
        ……… AS state,
        ……… AS `elec`
    FROM    tbl_states …

), tbl_sums AS (

    -- Final grouping query
    SELECT
        `state`,
        SUM(NOT `elec`) AS `vls`,
        SUM(`elec`) AS `vae`,
        count(`state`) AS `all`
    FROM tbl_states
    GROUP BY `state`
    ORDER BY `state`

)

-- Additional query which could be avoided if left as simple as this but it will not stay as simple as this
SELECT `state`, `vae`, `vls`, `all` FROM tbl_sums
```

This query makes statistics on two kinds of objects which can each have **8 different states** (*bad*, *longrun*, *lost*, *maint*, *ok*, *removed*, *run* or *warn*), so the results is a tiny view of only **8 rows** and **3 columns** (*vls*, *vae* and both).

On my server it needs about **500 mS** to execute, which is acceptable.

Now I want to add rows for creating some combined states, so I replaced the last SELECT by this **UNION**:

```
SELECT `state`, `vae`, `vls`, `all` FROM tbl_sums
UNION
SELECT 'all_sta',SUM(`vls`),SUM(`vae`),SUM(`all`) FROM tbl_sums WHERE `state` IN ('ok','warn','bad','maint')
UNION
SELECT 'all_run',SUM(`vls`),SUM(`vae`),SUM(`all`) FROM tbl_sums WHERE `state` IN ('run','longrun')
UNION
SELECT 'operative',SUM(`vls`),SUM(`vae`),SUM(`all`) FROM tbl_sums WHERE `state` IN ('ok','warn','run','longrun')
UNION
SELECT 'unusable',SUM(`vls`),SUM(`vae`),SUM(`all`) FROM tbl_sums WHERE `state` IN ('bad','maint')
UNION
SELECT 'present',SUM(`vls`),SUM(`vae`),SUM(`all`) FROM tbl_sums WHERE `state` IN ('ok','warn','bad','maint','run','longrun')
UNION
SELECT 'missing',SUM(`vls`),SUM(`vae`),SUM(`all`) FROM tbl_sums WHERE `state` IN ('removed','lost')
UNION
SELECT 'total',SUM(`vls`),SUM(`vae`),SUM(`all`) FROM tbl_sums
```

I works fine, but I am very surprised to observe that the query needs now about **4 seconds** to run, thus **8 times** the initial **500 mS**, likely because I am reusing the last **WITH** element **8 times**.

Apparently MariaDB execute this by computing **8 times** the whole sub-query chain instead of temporarily storing the last one and reusing it **8 times**, whereas I was expecting it to be able to reuse the last tiny result in not even a millisecond.

If I use **EXPLAIN** on the last query, I get a result like this :

[image: EXPLAIN on the above SQL query]

… where we could clearly see that the whole sub-queries are effectively explored **8 times**.

So I'd like to know if I made something bad, or if I should change some settings in order to have it working better, or if this is simply a bug in MariaDB (version **10.3.29** in this case), as **WITH** is a quite new feature in MariaDB.

I know I could create a temporary table, but as it is very complicated to execute multiple statements for **ONE** result in my application, I was precisely expecting to use WITH in order to avoid it.

This is likely irrelevant, but the server is running on Linux Debian 10.

Comment: It's very possible that you've hit some bug in the optimizer. I'd suggest opening a bug report on the [MariaDB Jira](https://jira.mariadb.org/projects/MDEV/). Including the `EXPLAIN` output is likely to be very helpful for the developers.

Comment: have you tried it in a newer version on fiddle or so

Comment: Fiddle? Importing (at least 6 tables of) my whole database? :-)

Comment: Can we at least see the schema for BK and the full query for `tbl_states`.  There seems to be a need for indexing or optimization somewhere in that area.

Comment: BK is the alias for the main table on which everything else is joined, it just has its PRIMARY KEY and another index. The table is read here from the beginning to the end, so no index is involved on it in this query.

I just upgraded one machine to Debian 11 and MariaDB 10.5.11, hoping it will work better afterwards. But the result is exactly the same with it.

If you want the whole query I can send it to you privately somewhere, but I prefer not posting it here.